# Pick from union type string

Tags: typescript

I have a union type, and I'd like to pick certain values from the union type. Is this possible? I've tried to use 'Pick', but this doesn't work on the union type.

e.g.

```
type FooType = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz';
type Extracted = : Pick<FooType, 'foo' | 'bar'>; // should contains only 'foo' and 'bar'
```

I've now tried various strategies, but cannot get this to work.

Comment: I was going to ask the same question. I'm very disappointed to find out there has been no answers at all. Did you find a way to do it?

Comment: I don't think Pick is intended to be used with unions. You would need to use an interface instead. Extract is probably your best option. @FedericoBellucci

Answer (score 22):

Try using `Extract` instead of `Pick`:

```js
type FooType = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz';
type Extracted = Extract<FooType, 'foo' | 'bar'>;
// type Extracted = 'foo' | 'bar'
```

Comment: One major incovenience with this is that it allows you to pick things that are not valid without giving compile time errors e.g. Extract<FooType, 'foo' | 'bing'> => 'foo'.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wasn't aware of the `Extract` keyword. SO doesn't give me the ability to accept the answer, I guess because too much time has passed.